# Get rid of the chapter number when I refer to table

Tags: floats, numbering

I use the following code for referring to an equation and table.

```
\let\originaleqref=\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}{Equation~\originaleqref}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table (\ref{#1})}
```

When I refer to an equation, there is no number of chapetr.
But when I refer to a table, there is a number of chapter.

[image]

[image]

Here is a small MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{OAGM}
%% For the accepted, final version, set this to the correct value:
\OAGMarXiv{1404.3538}

\usepackage{float} % fix the table
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsopn}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{breqn} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib }
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\section{1}
\subsection{2}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
 a & b\\\midrule
 \label{Tab a simple table}\end{tabularx}


I have to cite the table ~\ref{Tab a simple table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One way would be to redefine the table number, dropping the chapter info, but this effects also the table number in the caption: `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}` for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - A downside of your proposed solution is that it doesn't deal with the fact the `table` number is probably reset to `0` at the start of each chapter. It's thus not enough to reset `\thetable`; it's also necessary to change the way the `table` counter variable is set and incremented.

Comment: @Mico: I do not want to reset the table number, just drop the chapter output format from `\thetable`. I agree with you if you meant a continous counting of tables.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - If you only reset the table number's display, there's a huge risk of seriously confusing your readers if you have, say, three chapters and tables in all three chapters: Does a cross-reference to "Table 1" refer to Table 1.1, 2.1, or 3.1?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I know, I basically wrote this in my first comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to change both the way tables are numbered *and* the way they are cross-referenced. I further assume you're using a document class such as `book` or `report` which numbers `table` and `figure` environments per chapter, starting at `1` at the start of each chapter.

To have these environments numbered (and thus also cross-referenced) continuously throughout the document, you could issue the following commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
```

Incidentally, instead of redefining `\eqref` and defining `\tref` in the ways you show in your posting, you could load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and use its `\cref` cross-referencing command; `\cref` will automatically prefix the item's type (e.g., equation, section, table) before the associated number, or numbers.

[*Image deleted. It turns out that the OP's problem was quite different from the way he/she had described it initially. See the addendum below for the actual solution.*]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\chapter{Uno}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\label{tab:1}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\label{fig:1}\end{figure}

\chapter{Due}
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\label{tab:2}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\label{fig:2}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\label{fig:3}\end{figure}

\chapter{Tre}
Here are cross-references to \cref{tab:1,tab:2,fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: After the OP posted a working example, it became clear that the "2.1" that showed up in the cross-reference was not associated with a `table` object at all, but with a subsection. (The OAGM document class does not feature a `\chapter` command at all, and it doesn't number `table` and `figure` items by section.) Below is a corrected form of the OP's MWE that shows the expected behavior (in terms of `table` numbers that show up in a cross-reference.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{OAGM}
%% For the accepted, final version, set this to the correct value:
\OAGMarXiv{1404.3538}
%% I've commented out duplicate package loading instructions...
\usepackage{float} % fix the table %% Why??
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
%%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{breqn} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\subsection{2}\label{subsec:xyz}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
 a & b\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{My first table}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
Here's a cross-reference to Table~\ref{tab:1}, and here's a cross-reference to Subsection~\ref{subsec:xyz}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the error message. 'Package chngcntr Error: chapter is not a cnouter'.

Comment: @Vivian - Which document class do you employ?

Comment: I submit the paper to a conference, actually a workshop. So I do not use a document class.

Comment: @Vivian: In any LaTeX document, the document class is the argument of the command `\documentclass`, which (in all likelihood) is *the very first instruction in your LaTeX document*.

Comment: yes. The conference asks 'For the final version, do not set any document class options.'

Comment: @Vivian - So you've been told not to use any *optional* arguments with the `\documentclass` instruction. However, this instruction also takes (exactly) one *mandatory* argument -- the document class itself. What does it say inside the curly braces of your document's `\documentclass` instruction?

Comment: Since the requirement, I  use \documentclass[]{OAGM}. The conference name is OAGM.

Comment: The OAGM documentclass does *not* feature a `\chapter` command, and it also does *not* number tables in "2.1", "2.2", etc. style. (Instead, they're numbered consecutively, i.e., `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.) Hence, it's not necessary either to load the `chngcntr` package and issue the `\counterwithout` statements. Could you please elaborate what you meant when you wrote "But when I refer to a table, there is a number of chapter"?

Comment: @Yes, of course. Please see figs in the question.

Comment: @Vivian - You've been asked several times to post an MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that generates the problem behavior you want to change. Posting screenshots some code fragments is not sufficient. The OAGM class does not provide the command `\chapter`, so whatever you're showing in the screenshot can *not* be a chapter number. Moreover, by itself, the class keeps `table` numbers simple; some package must be interfering with the numbering. Please post a real MWE if you want people to have a chance to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: First I am sorry that I did not provide a MWE. At first, I really try to make one. But there are errors.And I have provided cls also. So I did not provide a MWE.

Comment: Hi. I write one. It is strange. At the beginning, it does not have the number of chapter. But later, it has. I try to find the problem but I do not find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting a compilable example. Your cross-reference to `table ~\ref{Tab a simple table}`, which generates "1.1", does *not* point to a `table` object but to the *subsection* numbered 1.1. Why? Because you don't actually have a `table` environment with a `\caption` command. Hence the command `\label{Tab a simple table}` actually points to the item whose number was most recently incremented via `\refstepcounter`, which happens to be a `subsection` counter. I'll post a corrected version of your MWE at the end of my answer.

Comment: Is there any method which I do not need to add table? Because I use `\textsuperscript{\ref{1}}` in the table, it will be wrong if I add `table`.

Comment: I suddenly found that I do no need to add {table} environment. I put \label behind \captionof, then it works.

Comment: you can try it. I do not know why it is Ok now.